# Python best way to check if key in dict and use value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
{
  'cashflowStatements': [
    {
      'endDate': '2019',
      'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': -40743000,
      'capitalExpenditures': -46141000
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 148919000,
      'endDate': '2018',
      'capitalExpenditures': -53753000
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -45493000,
      'endDate': '2017',
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -19651000,
      'endDate': '2016',
      'capitalExpenditures': -26266000
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add the values to a variable, if they are in the dictionary.

Currently I have this solution for that:

```py
       for year in dict['cashflowStatements']:
            freeCashflow = 0
            if 'totalCashFromOperatingActivities' in year:
                freeCashflow += year['totalCashFromOperatingActivities']
            if 'capitalExpenditures' in year:
                freeCashflow += year['capitalExpenditures']
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe with less lines of code?

Comment: `+= year.get(key, 0)`?

Comment: Yep, haven't known this yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
for year in dict['cashflowStatements']:
    freeCashflow = year.get('totalCashFromOperatingActivities', 0) + year.get('capitalExpenditures', 0)
```

Comment: If we want `freeCashflow` to be intialized with the data present in the last dict of list ONLY, then why to iterate the entire list ? We can simply get last dict from list and use that.

Comment: Maybe the code is not complete. More logic to be added in the loop. It depends on the questioners requirement

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic would be to use list comprehension like this -

```
d = {
  'cashflowStatements': [
    {
      'endDate': '2019',
      'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': -40743000,
      'capitalExpenditures': -46141000
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 148919000,
      'endDate': '2018',
      'capitalExpenditures': -53753000
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -45493000,
      'endDate': '2017',
    },
    {
      'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -19651000,
      'endDate': '2016',
      'capitalExpenditures': -26266000
    }
  ]
}

print(sum([year.get('totalCashFromOperatingActivities', 0) + year.get('capitalExpenditures', 0) for year in d['cashflowStatements']]))
```

Output: `-166903000`

Also looking at the question it seems like we want `freeCashflow` to be initialized with the sum of data present in last dict of list ONLY, then use below code.

```
print(d["cashflowStatements"][-1].get('totalCashFromOperatingActivities', 0) + d["cashflowStatements"][-1].get('capitalExpenditures', 0))
```

Output: `-26266000`

Comment: 'freeCashflow' is reinitialized in each loop. So I think this won't behave the same way as in question